# Cross compile from Ubuntu arm to Ubuntu x86

Tags: ubuntu, arm, x86-64, cross-compiling

I develop software which should run on a Linux x86-64 system. I recently got a MacbookPro with Apple silicon, and thought I could compile my program in an Ubuntu virtual machine (Parallels), but did not consider that I need to run Ubuntu arm as the virtual machine. Hence my question: Is it possible to cross compile from Ubuntu arm to x86? If yes, is the toolchain maybe in the packages?

Comment: Ubuntu has packages like `g++-x86-64-linux-gnu` ( https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/devel/g++-x86-64-linux-gnu) for cross-compiling.  That was just the first google hit; I'm sure there's a similar package in a current Ubuntu release.

Comment: Docker for macOS allows x86_64 emulation, it's slow but works fine.